# JS routing issue

Tags: javascript, angular

I have tried my best but yet to find out why my routing isn't working.
I am trying to create a local android app.
Here's my src/app files  if needed
`app.component.spec.ts suset.jpeg login app.component.css main-page app.component.ts app.module.ts`

Here's my code:
This is the main page (for the login) - app.components.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div class="login-container">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1 class="logo-text">DIGITAL PAY</h1>
            </div>
            <h1 class="login-heading label-text">LOGIN</h1>

            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="username" class="label-text">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" [(ngModel)]="username" class="login-input" />
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="password" class="label-text">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" [(ngModel)]="password" class="login-input" />
            </div>

            <button class="login-button" (click)="login()">Login</button>

            <p *ngIf="errorMessage" class="error-message">{{ errorMessage }}</p>
            <p *ngIf="response" class="response-message">{{ response }}</p>
            <div class="signup-link label-text">
                Don't have an account? <a (click)="goToSignUp()">Sign up</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    errorMessage: string;
    response: any;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
        this.username = '';
        this.password = '';
        this.errorMessage = '';
        this.response = '';
    }


    login() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:5000/login';
        // const url = 'http://10.0.2.2:5000/login';
        const data = { username: this.username, password: this.password };

        this.http.post(url, data).subscribe(
            (response: any) => {
                const user_id = response.user_id;
                if (user_id === "None") {
                    this.response = '';
                    this.errorMessage = 'Invalid username or password.';
                } else {
                    this.errorMessage = '';
                    this.response = user_id;
                    this.router.navigate(['/main-page']);
                }
            },
            (error) => {
                this.errorMessage = "error";
            }
        );
    }
    goToSignUp() {
        // this.router.navigate(['/signup']);
        this.response = "Under maintenance!"
    }
}
```

This is the app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MainPageComponent } from './main-page/main-page.component';
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainPageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'main-page', component: MainPageComponent }
    ], { enableTracing: true })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I don't understand why the route to '/main' doesn't work.
The login is succefully but it isn't moving to the next page (the main)

Comment: You mention "/main" but you code has "main-page"